# In iOS, is there a method to make a button move around arc line or circle?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a custom control like the picture below, it is too complicated to draw all the images using core graphics. So I use the images designer give, but the problem is how to make the small circle(which is actually a button) on the big white circle(which is an UIImageView) move aroud the big circle? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: You can use sin() and cos() function to calculate the exact position or make an arc path and make the button move along the path. See this https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/animations-explained/ and scroll down to Animation Along a Path section.

Comment: @sikhapol Thank you for your reply~~ I have implemented it by changing the button's center point continually according to its changing angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate all circumference points. Just set centre of your image to the points calculated by you. Automatically your image will start moving in circle.
[image]

Comment: Um, yes~ I did as you said! Best wishes for you kind guys╰(￣▽￣)╮